# Scanning multiple Strings to ArrayList returns unexpected result. (Java, simple, beginner)

Tags: java, arraylist

Here's the code I mean:

```
public class ArrayTest {
    private static ArrayList<String> atf() {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

        while(true) {
            Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = i.next();

            System.out.println(input);

            array.add(input);

            System.out.println("Here i am!");

            if(i.next().equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Cyka");
                break;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    public ArrayTest() {
        System.out.println(atf().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' '));
    }
}
```

I get only some inputs to trigger the "Here I am!".
It is really confusing me why only every second or so input will be added to the ArrayList. As a complete beginner I hope the problem isn't too obvious and that you guys can help me.
Much regards.

---

**Edit after initial feedback:**

```
public class ArrayTest {
private static ArrayList<String> atf() {

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(i.hasNext() && !(i.next().equals("exit"))) {

        System.out.println(i.next());
        String string = i.next();
        array.add(string);
    }   
    i.close();

    return array;
}

public ArrayTest() {
    System.out.println(atf().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' '));
}
```

Every 3rd "string" will be printed out.
were the changes alright?

Comment: First, you should declare the scanner outstide the loop. Then, you will wait a value to check if `exit` or not. You want to check if `input` == `"exit"` before you add it to the array or not and exit the loop. And close the Scanner at the end too ;)

Comment: Edit the question with that information ;)

Comment: Every call of `next` will wait an input from you. Store one input then work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why only every second input is added is that the others are consumed by your "exit"-check.

You should instead write it like this:

```
try (Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        String next = i.next();

        list.add(next);

        if ("exit".equals(next)) {
            System.out.println("Cyka");
            break;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

The big difference here is that `Scanner.next()` is only called once, not twice. This is why every input is added to the list, while your original code "drops" the input that was recorded for the "exit"-check.

Creating the scanner in a try statement will make sure that it is closed at the end, as well.

Comment: The "try-with-resource" is clearly a good point. Do note that this is risky in a method like this, if OP call `atf` twice, it won't work

Comment: You are welcome. I hope I made it easy to understand what was going on. @AxelH, could you explain why it wouldn't work? Not too experienced with InputStreams and Scanners myself. I tried calling aft() twice, and it gave me a NoSuchElementException when calling next() the first time on the second run. But doesn't the scanner get newly initialized? Do you have some resource to read about this?

Comment: When you close a `Scanner`, you will close the stream link to it, in that case the `System.in`. The problem with `System.in` as the name class tell it, is that it is initialize by the System (the JVM) during the main initialization, before the call of the `main` method. So once you have closed it, you can't reopen it. With the initial code, it was not a problem since we had Scanners leaking everywhere (not good either). When you use a Scanner like this, it is good to let the `main` method to create and close it. You just need to declare it static or share it in parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is quite obvious now that you explain it. @Robschmok I had added the try block in order to close the Scanner after you are done using it. But in this example it might have the side effect that you also close the `System.in` stream as Axel explained, so you cannot use it again. If this is only a small playground project, it doesn't really matter whether you close the scanner or not, but in a bigger project, you should figure this out.